showing one object from an array at time
i am designing an endless runner game. where i want to show one of the difficuties from an array i have made. i have difficulties 1,2,3 and i am assigning its index each time and want to get them set active. But they become all the indexes or the difficulty level.
I Wrote the following code in Start method.
public GameObject[] difficulties;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    int randomDiffi = Random.Range(0, difficulties.Length);
    difficulties[randomDiffi].gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

now I want to make active 1 defficulty level in between 1 and 3. each its needs to be radomly vary not all the difficulties to be loaded as it does.

Your code works, but perhaps you forgot to set all gameobjects active to false?

Okay, you're on the right track, but now you just need to make sure you activate only the 'random' one that got selected.
First, make sure on start, before you select at random, you have them all deactivated like so (if you didn't do it manually--which is preferred, so we wouldn't need to do this)
foreach (GameObject difficulty in difficulties)
{
    difficulty.SetActive(false);
}

Then you select one and set that as active:
int randomDiffi = Random.Range(0, difficulties.Length);
difficulties[randomDiffi].SetActive(true);

